# Reportlab как сохранить Drawing в виде изображения

Tags: python

Есть ли возможность через Reportlab сохранить Drawing в виде изображения. Есть куча кода создающего графики, до этого я включал их в исходный pdf документ, сейчас требования изменились, нужно полученные графики внедрять в HTML. 
Было типа:

```
drawing = Drawing(310, 190)
lc = LinePlot()
...
drawing.add(lc)
return drawing
```

Сейчас их нужно сохранять отдельно в виде изображения, не как часть PDF.

Answer (score 1):

Была ошибка в генерации LinePlot, вот работающий вариант:

```
from reportlab.graphics.charts.linecharts import HorizontalLineChart
from reportlab.graphics.shapes import Drawing

drawing = Drawing(400, 200)
data = [
    (13, 5, 20, 22, 37, 45, 19, 4),
    (5, 20, 46, 38, 23, 21, 6, 14)
]

lc = HorizontalLineChart()

lc.x = 50
lc.y = 50
lc.height = 125
lc.width = 300
lc.data = data
lc.joinedLines = 1
catNames = 'Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug'.split(' ')
lc.categoryAxis.categoryNames = catNames
lc.categoryAxis.labels.boxAnchor = 'n'
lc.valueAxis.valueMin = 0
lc.valueAxis.valueMax = 60
lc.valueAxis.valueStep = 15
lc.lines[0].strokeWidth = 2
lc.lines[1].strokeWidth = 1.5
drawing.add(lc)
drawing.save(formats=['png'], outDir='.', fnRoot='aaa', verbose='hello')
```